# SQL's Rownumber with Linq-to-entities

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am converting my project to use EF and also want to covert stored procedures into Linq-to-entities queries.

This my SQL query (simple version)  that I have trouble to convert:

```
SELECT 
       CategoryID, Title as CategoryTitle,Description, 
       LastProductTitle,LastProductAddedDate
FROM
(
    SELECT
        C.CategoryID, C.Title,C.Description, C.Section,
        P.Title as LastProductTitle, P.AddedDate as LastProductAddedDate,                                          
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.CategoryID ORDER BY P.AddedDate DESC) AS Num

    FROM 
         Categories C         
         LEFT JOIN Products P ON P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
) OuterSelect

WHERE 
     OuterSelect.Num = 1
```

In words: I want to return all Categories (from Categories table) and title and date of addition of the product (from Products table) that was added last to this category.

How can I achieve this using Entity frame work query?
In most efficient way.

Comment: Do you want a solution in EF, or do you want the most efficient way? The most efficient way is to write it in SQL. You could do it even faster than your current method if instead of a windowing function you use CROSS APPLY.

Comment: @Mark Byers, so do you suggest to leave it as stored procedure?
Can you please show how to use here cross apply?

Comment: Well it depends. You said you wanted a solution in EF but you also said you wanted the most efficient way. If you can live with a solution with OK but probably not optimal performance then an EF solution would be fine and more maintainable. The CROSS APPLY method is quite complicated - you can read about it here: http://explainextended.com/2009/11/30/sql-server-selecting-records-holding-group-wise-maximum/. What is best also depends on how many rows you have. If you only have a few rows then the table scan might be the fastest way.

Comment: @Mark Byers, regarding the cross apply i think i'll skip this cause IMHO partition  is not too bad and it's widely used.
And i still want the EF solution, I will test both of the solution and decide which one is better for me. So if you can please show the EF solution,

Comment: The EF will use `CROSS APPLY` itself if you (1) write the LINQ correctly and (2) use `ProviderManifestToken` = 2008.

Answer (score -1):

Is a Row_Number() needed in this case?

The following returns the most recent order for all customers in the Northwind database:

```
from c in Customers
join o in Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
group o by  new { c.CustomerID, c.ContactName}  into g
select new {
 CustomerID = g.Key.CustomerID,
 Name = g.Key.ContactName,
 OrderDate = g.Max(a=> a.OrderDate)
}
```

The query created (from LinqPad) is

```
SELECT MAX([t1].[OrderDate]) AS [OrderDate], [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[ContactName] AS [Name]
FROM [Customers] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Orders] AS [t1] ON [t0].[CustomerID] = [t1].[CustomerID]
GROUP BY [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[ContactName]
```

This one does a left join instead

```
from c in Customers
         join o in Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID into g
         from a in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
         group a by new { c.CustomerID, c.ContactName}  into g
         select new
         {
             g.Key.CustomerID,
             g.Key.ContactName,
             RecentOrder  = g.Max(a=> a.OrderDate) 
         }
```

and the query generated is

```
SELECT MAX([t1].[OrderDate]) AS [RecentOrder], [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[ContactName]
FROM [Customers] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Orders] AS [t1] ON [t0].[CustomerID] = [t1].[CustomerID]
GROUP BY [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[ContactName]
```

Comment: I didn't test this query yet, but i don't like the group by, I have about 10 columns that I need to return so this will require me to group by all this columns, right?

Comment: after checking this query doesn't return what is needed